Random Walk with given end-point
A person starts from $x=0$ and either goes one step right or left with equal probability until it reaches either $x=-2$ or $x=10$, let $N$ denote the number of steps taken by the person and $Y$ denote the end state.
Find $E(N|Y=10)$.
I ran a Monti-Carlo simulation and found the answer to be around 46.7 but don't know how to get the answer formally. I know $()=20$ and using the formula $((|))=()$ I got one equation involving $(|=10)$ and $(|=−2)$ but couldn't make any progress. Any help is appreciated.

Let $X_t$ be the position of the walk after $t$ steps. I think it is reasonable to consider
$$Y_t = t (X_t + 2).$$
The point is that if $\tau$ is the stopping time of hitting $-2$ or $10$, then $Y_{\tau} = 0$ if $X_{\tau} = -2$, and $Y_{\tau} = 12 \tau$ if $X_{\tau} = 10$. So we have
$$\mathbb{E}[\tau | X_{\tau} = 10] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[\tau \mathbf{1}_{X_{\tau} = 10}]}{\mathbb{P}[X_\tau = 10]} = 6\mathbb{E}[\tau \mathbf{1}_{X_{\tau} = 10}] = \mathbb{E}[Y_{\tau}] / 2.$$
Let $F_t$ be the standard filtration. We have
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_{t + 1} | F_t] = Y_t + X_t + 2$$
To make $Y_{t + 1}$ into a martingale, we note that
$$\mathbb{E}[X_{t + 1}^2 | F_t] = X_t^2 + 1,$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X_{t + 1}^3 | F_t] = X_t^3 + 3X_t$$
so
$$Z_t = Y_t - \frac{1}{3}X_t^3 - 2X_t^2$$
is a martingale with $Z_0 = 0$. By optional stopping, we obtain
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_{\tau}] = \mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{3}X_\tau^3 + 2X_\tau^2] = \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{16}{3} + \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1600}{3} = \frac{280}{3}.$$
So we conclude that
$$\mathbb{E}[\tau | X_\tau = 10] = \frac{140}{3} = 46.66\cdots.$$

Thank you for the brilliant solution. Just a side note for general $a$ and $b$ (in this example $a=2$ and $b=10$) answer is $\frac{2ab + b^2}{3}$

Very nice solution!
